# How can I find out the IO throughput of an external storage device connected to a MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, external-disk

In 'Disk' of Activity Monitor' I can only see the aggregate numbers

[image: IO]

However I want a way to measure an individual connected device.

Reason: I have recently purchased a Sandisk SSD drive and used it for time machine backup. I want to get some quantitative measurements in term of performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice leightweight monitoring tool is bwm-ng (installed with [brew](https://brew.sh/)):

It shows network as well as disk activity:

```
$: bwm-ng -i ioservice
  bwm-ng v0.6.2 (probing every 0.500s), press 'h' for help
  input: ioservice disk IO type: rate
  /         iface                   Rx                   Tx                Total
  ==============================================================================
            disk0:        4063.49 KB/s            0.00 KB/s         4063.49 KB/s
            disk1:           0.00 KB/s         2579.36 KB/s         2579.36 KB/s
            disk2:        4063.49 KB/s            0.00 KB/s         4063.49 KB/s
            disk3:           0.00 KB/s         4000.00 KB/s         4000.00 KB/s
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            total:        8143.14 KB/s         6584.49 KB/s        14727.63 KB/s
```

The example displayed is disk activity related to the command `sudo asr ...` (cloning an APFS disk0s2/disk2 to disk1s2/disk3).

Answer (score 1):

A popular disk speed testing tool is "[Blackmagic Disk Speed Test](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjj-IuLw7LnAhVP2qQKHYCQDFYQFjABegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fblackmagic-disk-speed-test%2Fid425264550%3Fmt%3D12&usg=AOvVaw2Z-pC4aYkV4KoJftFgaUXi)". You can download this from the App Store and get quantitative measurements for your new SSD.